# How to omit "src/main/java" folder from Maven build?

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have a project where I have my HTML and JavaScript files in `src/main/webapp/..`. But in the same project I have `.java` files in `src/main/java folder`. But when I'm building the project I dont want to use those java files at all. They are broken files which are used as skeletons for another purpose. I have a `pom` as following.

```xml
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  <source>1.7</source>
  <target>1.7</target>
  <warSourceExcludes>src/main/java/**</warSourceExcludes>
</configuration>
```

But still I get errors related to the java codes. How can I fix this?

Comment: The war plugin does not normally include the source files. It will however compile them and put the java files there. What do you mean by "They are broken files and are used as skeletons for another purpose" Maven is really picky about it's conventions, so you probably should intentionally break them.

Comment: They are copied from another project. Which are does not have many references. But I use those clsses to generate the HTML/javascript using another tool. So I would like to keep thease classes in the same project , so in future its easy to refer what generated what.

Comment: If they do not belong to that project just remove them from src/main/java.

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround for this problem.

```
 <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <!--  Here we point to an empty folder, so the maven will not complain about broken java codes -->
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/javaempty</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
```

Now the maven is compiling the `javaempty` folder without any complaints :)